# ASP.NET SignalR not working on Xamarin Webview

Tags: asp.net, xamarin, webview, xamarin.ios, signalr

I have implemented text messaging using ASP.NET SignalR JavaScript Library, which is working fine from desktop browsers.
But not working while I am loading text messaging URL on Xamarin WebView. I have debugged the application using the iOS simulator and safari browser, in Safari console tab did not found any error but in networks, tab getting  "An error occurred trying to load the resources" for  /signalr/hubs. Other than that I don't have any clue for this error.

I am not sure why ASP.NET SignalR not working on Xamarin Webview, could please let me know what I am missing? what should I do to resolve this error? I will greatly appreciate your help with this.

Thanks in advance.

Mahabub

Comment: yes SSL based, HTTPS

Comment: our website using a real CA

Comment: Any new about this problem ?